# php Generate random numbers, save to database without repetition

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a bet generator, where each user will generate a sequence of unique numbers within the available amount. I managed to generate the numbers but I couldn't eliminate the ones in the database, in another code I can eliminate the ones from the database but it doesn't generate the amount of numbers. How to generate the right amount of numbers, eliminating those already in the db.

In this code I can generate the sequence but it does not eliminate the ones that are already in the database:

```
  function lottery($maxn = "49", $maxb = "6")
    {

        include_once 'conecta_e1.php';

        $maxn = 60;

        $new_array = array();

        $quer = "SELECT num_sorte FROM tbl_aposta";

        $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $quer);
        while ($query_get = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $new_array[] = $query_get["numeros_compra"];

            srand((float) microtime() * 1000000);

            while (1 > 0) {
                do { //Aqui gera os números mas não fil
                    $lottery[] = rand(0, $maxn);
                    $lottery = array_unique($lottery);
                    $new_array = array_unique($new_array);
                } while (in_array($lottery, $new_array));

                if (sizeof($lottery) == $maxb) break;
            }
            sort($lottery);
            return implode(", ", $lottery);
            
        }
    }
    $lotterynums = lottery();

    echo $lotterynums;
    exit;
```

Doing it this way, I can compare but it only generates one number at a time

```
do{ 
        $rand = rand(00,04);
}while (in_array($rand, $new_array));
```

Comment: Generate the numbers, sort them and store a hash. Then generate new ones and compare the hash. Repeat, when a hash collides.